# Android create a custom titles but still maintain android.holo.light theme in my spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-theme

Hi my app uses custom titles therefore I have to use a custom theme which looks like this`<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
    </style>`
I'd like to have a Spinner the drop down menu which look like the one in the android:Theme.Holo.Light Just the spinner is there any way to do this
please help

Answer (score 0):

On your manifest add `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` inside the activity tag your spinner is in.

```
<activity
        android:name="your.package.name.YourActivityWithSpinnerInIt"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. I already have the custom titles working what I would like to have as well is have the spinners that we see in android:Theme.Holo.Light